# A Word that means "to adapt or improve, to conform to a higher standard"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find ***or invent*** a word that suggests a system might be "adapted or improved to conform to a higher standard". A verb, noun, adjective or even adverb would be acceptable, but so far I haven't found quite what I'm looking for.

**Context Examples:**

"We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise [conformity to a higher standard]."

"I believe we need to change our approach. We need to [adapt to conform to a higher standard]."

"It will take some time to write an article that's more [improved to conform to a higher standard] than I've written before."

Comment: It's not obvious to me why "upgrade" itself won't do for most contexts, in that this can be used without necessarily elaborating on the "higher standard" to which adherence is being proposed. Also I don't think *written articles* are in the same class as (computer?) systems, in that they're not really produced in the context of rapidly evolving standards. Probably just *polished* or similar would do for such material.

Comment: In "We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise [conformity to a higher standard]" and "It will take some time to write an article that's more [improved to conform to a higher standard] than I've written before" you presumably just want a word meaning "conformity" because you already have "greater"/"more" modifying it.

Comment: This will likely be controversial, but I think I've arrived at a possible alternative: conscend.

Comment: Conscend is not a word (to my knowledge), but it seems to fit the bill perfectly -- "con" meaning "with", suggesting alignment as in "conform"; "-scend" meaning "climb" as in "ascend", "descend". So "conscend" means to "climb to meet" or similar. It' *feels* like it could/should be a word!

Comment: It has the added benefit of sounding similar to "consent" (to agree with) and is very close to "conform" so its meaning can be easily inferred in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate thought was [kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen). It isn't strictly English, and it isn't strictly a verb, but it is known widely in some circles.

We need to kaizen our Enterprise compatibility.

We need to kaizen our approach.

I need to take time to kaizen my writing skills to make this article better.

This isn't strictly English, but you said you were open to inventing a word.

Comment: Can you add what it means?

Comment: @MrHen sure, added a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: Please don't use kaizen as a verb when "improve" with a well-chosen adverb will do.

Answer (score 7):

I think the word you're looking for is

> Evolve

It means almost ***exactly*** that.

> Evolve: Develop esp. from a simple to a more complex form.

But you could also use

> Robust: n(of a process or system, esp. an economic one) Able to withstand or overcome adverse conditions

We use it to describe computer applications all the time.

Comment: Ah, but *evolve* virtually by definition doesn't imply upgrading to a higher standard, because "Evolution is blind", as they say. And *robust* explicitly names the particular attribute one seeks to improve - which wouldn't do for an *article*, for instance.

Comment: I agree with Fumble. Evolve has the sense of change, but not of improvement.

Comment: Darwin's 'Evolution' has nothing to do with the usage of the word 'evolve'. 
Based on the definition 'Develop esp...', and the definition of develop, 'Grow or cause to grow and become more mature, advanced, or elaborate',it sounds to me like 'evolve' definitely means to 'improve'.
Evolution being blind is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think you need anything other than either *improve* or *conform* in most cases, because greater conformity will nearly always be an improvement at any rate. In general I think more context would help if you want to cut out some more words; in your examples, we don't know a great deal about the situations described.

> "We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise *conformity*

This is probably what you mean; how can greater conformity not necessarily be an improvement in itself?."

> "I believe we need to change our approach. We need to *conform to a higher standard* / *raise our standards*."

The above would probably work all right: why one word?

> "It will take some time to write an article *to a higher standard* than [what] I've written before."

Comment: I like "higher standard," but I disagree that "conform" has a positive connotation. More the opposite; it is a word that makes me think of bureaucracies or peer pressure.

Comment: @LarryOBrien: Okay, I suppose the positive aspect of this conformity lies in the fact that all of these example sentences actually strive for greater conformity, not so much in the word itself.

Answer (score 1):

A few options (assuming a little mix and matching):

- strict
- compliance
- adherence
- accuracy

> We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise compliance.
>
> I believe we need to change our approach. We need stricter compliance.
>
> It will take some time to write an article that's more compliant than I've written before.

This is especially useful when joined with *standards*:

> We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise standards compliance.
>
> I believe we need to change our approach. We need stricter standards compliance.
>
> It will take some time to write an article that's more standards compliant than I've written before.

Comment: Compliance is the closest I could come up with, too. It doesn't necessarily suggest an improvement, and unfortunately it tends to imply that the goal is to align with some predetermined set of rules, which is not really what I'm going for.. but I haven't been able to come up with anything better myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty open field. I would go with ***ameliorated***.

Comment: To me that has the overtone of a remedy to make a bad situation somewhat better.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest word that comes to mind is *surpass* and its various conjugations.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be  **overhaul** ?

A few more tries below:

"We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise **modernity**."

"I believe we need to change our approach. We need to **level up** / **modernise** / **overhaul** / **renovate** our approach."

"It will take some time to write an article that's more **state of the art** than what I've written before."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **optimize**, **optimization**, **optimal**, **optimality**, **proficient**, **proficiency**.

If you really want to talk about meeting some norm, "conform" or "converge" perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

**Improve**, **optimize** or **refine** should be adequate to most occasions, **glorify** if you need extra sarcasm...

Answer (score 0):

ingenuity, innovation, catch up, exemplar, exemplarity, pioneer, perfect (as in the verb), polish (figurative sense, verb), enhance, overhaul, redesign, gentrify (this does carry a negative connotation), lead the curve, set (with object) apart, punch up, aim higher, step it up, sophisticated, tinker, squish bugs, spiff(en?) up, efficiency, elegant, elevate, set the bar higher, live up to (expectations), tweak, revamp, better (as a verb with object), hone, fine-tune, revise, all came to mind

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Some of these are only used in specific contexts, others are not necessarily about the improvement themselves, but the idea or intent to improve. And please focus on a few words, and give proper definitions and your reasoning behind them.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the most universal fit is *edify*.

> - We are upgrading the current system for greater Enterprise **edification**.
> - I believe we need to change our approach. We need to **edify** it.
> - It will take some time to write an article that's more **edified** than I've written before.

This may not be a typical way of using it, but certainly works.
Other good choices are: *refine, transcend, sophisticate, enrich, reform, enhance, excel, idealize, revise, advance, acquiesce,* or even simply *improve*.

It is mostly a matter of finding the one with proper connotation ("idealization, reluctance, room for further improvement", &c.) and the proper form for each use.

You may be really looking for multiple/different words (by these examples) or perhaps a phrase.

Comment: [*Edify*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edify?q=edify) only means *improve* when it's applied to someone's education.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewLeach. The second and third examples are not proper. An approach or an article cannot be edified. They can, however, be edifying (the unmentioned implicit people whose upliftment will be an effect of the approach or the article). Collective nouns are acceptable, however. Your first example is, I think, fine.